# Difference between `brew services start mysql` and `mysql.server start`

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I installed MySQL using homebrew `brew install mysql`, and I noticed that MySQL can be managed with two different methods:

`brew services start mysql`  
and 
`mysql.server start`

Is there any difference when starting the service using brew services vs starting it with the normal mysql.server method? Or are they basically the same thing, just a different alias?

It appears they both use the same executable: `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysqld`

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the help message of `brew services`, when you run

```sh
brew services start mysql
```

it installs and starts the service formula at login (or at boot if you run the command with `sudo`). It means you will have now a plist file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` (or in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` if you run the command with `sudo`). For mysql, the plist file is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mysql</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--bind-address=127.0.0.1</string>
    <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

it means that by default `mysqld_safe` is called with the `--bind-address=127.0.0.1` and `--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql` command line options.

when you run

```sh
mysql.server start
```

you directly execute the mysql script located in `/usr/local/bin/mysql.server`.

The main difference is that with the `brew services` version, you run `mysqld_safe` which, according to its `man` page:

> adds some safety features such as restarting the server when an error occurs and logging runtime information to an error log file.