# LINUX MINT mysql

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling

ERROR LINUX MINT MYSQL

1. Can You explain what happened?
2. I can't start in xampp
3. What configuration should I change ?

**I already change /var/lib/mysql/ to chmod 777**

```
    2019-02-27T16:35:55.748379Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.748447Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.919606Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.921605Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 16788 ...
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.926137Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.926173Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.926182Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.926190Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.926198Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.926206Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.926511Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.926644Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.928888Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.945234Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.948312Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.958383Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.958517Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
        2019-02-27T16:35:55.958539Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
        2019-02-27T16:35:56.559302Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
        2019-02-27T16:35:56.559365Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
        2019-02-27T16:35:56.559381Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
        2019-02-27T16:35:56.559404Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
        2019-02-27T16:35:56.559441Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
        2019-02-27T16:35:56.559583Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
        2019-02-27T16:35:56.560410Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check rights on your filesystem :

```
The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
```

The folder containing ibdata1 seems to not be writable by mysql user.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the file `ibdata1` is indeed writable `-rw-rw--w-`.

The full path of this file is at `/usr/local/var/mysql/ibdata1`. 
But it doen't help if I make the file writable by all -- I get the same error.

Stumbled upon an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43418955/difference-between-brew-services-start-mysql-and-mysql-server-start/43835281) by remove `*.err` and it did it for me!  Hope it helps you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22432605)

Comment: Just updated the answer with a solution that helped me.